# How can I create hidden folder in windows with flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I created a folder to store user and program data and I keep some assets there. But I want to make the folder private so that users cannot access it from outside.

Comment: Can you define "users" and "outside"? Do you mean others users logging into the same windows machine?

Comment: no, I don't want the user to access the assets I have stored for the program. Actually I just want to create hidden folder.

Comment: There are no such things as "hidden" folders a user cannot access in Windows. You could set the "hidden" attribute, but that is just the view in the default file explorer used in Windows. There is no authorization involved hindering the user from accessing the files. Generally speaking, for all systems and all programming languages: if you install something on the client, the user of the client system will have access to it. You can make it harder for computer illiterates, but any normal user will be able to access it. After all, it's *their* device.